# Значение input.value не приводится к числу

Tags: javascript

Тип данных в input.value должен приводиться к числу через `parseInt`, но не срабатывает. Как привести к числу вводимые данные?

```js
let pallets = document.getElementsByClassName('pallets');
let totalPallets = document.getElementById('totalPallets');
  
for(let i=0; i < pallets.length; i++) {
 pallets[i].addEventListener('input', function(event){
   let num = parseInt(pallets[i].value);
   console.log('total: ' + totalPallets.value);
    console.log('current: ' + pallets[i].value);
    console.log('total = ' + totalPallets.value - num);
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}
div input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" id="totalPallets" value="33">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все приводится.

Проблема в строке:

```
console.log('total = ' + totalPallets.value - num);
```

так как не расставлены скобки сначала выполняется `+`, получается **строка**: *"total=33"* из-за этого при попытке привести это значение к числу получается `NaN`.

Для решения достаточно просто расставить скобки:

```
console.log('total = ' + (totalPallets.value - num));
```

```js
let pallets = document.getElementsByClassName('pallets');
let totalPallets = document.getElementById('totalPallets');

for (let i = 0; i < pallets.length; i++) {
  pallets[i].addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    let num = parseInt(pallets[i].value);
    console.log('total: ' + totalPallets.value);
    console.log('current: ' + pallets[i].value);
    console.log('total = ' + (totalPallets.value - num));
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}

div input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
  <input type="text" id="totalPallets" value="33">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let pallets = $('.pallets');
let totalPallets = $('#totalPallets');

$(pallets).on('input', (event) => {
  console.log($(event.currentTarget).val());
  console.log('total:', typeof +totalPallets.val());
  console.log('current', typeof +$(event.currentTarget).val());
  console.log('total =', typeof (+totalPallets.val() -$(event.currentTarget).val()));
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}
div input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" class="pallets">
<input type="text" id="totalPallets" value="33">

</div>
```

Comment: Это решение на jQuery. Мне нужно на чистом JS.

Comment: Перепишите на javascript если вам нужно, но смысл тут совсем не в выборе DOM элементов, а в операциях в console.log